# HTTP response code in Java

Tags: java, url, connection, httpresponse

This is the code I used :

```
class ResponseCodeCheck 
{

public static void main (String args[]) throws Exception
{

    URL url = new URL("http://www.amazon.co.jp/gp/seller/sell-your-stuff.html");
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    connection.connect();

    int code = connection.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("Response code of the object is "+code);
    if (code==200)
    {
        System.out.println("OK");
    }
}
}
```

And it gave 404 for the URL while that URL is working fine. 
Any reason why ?

Comment: what does that mean? If i change url to 'http://www.google.com', above code works fine.

Comment: You say the URL is working fine. Did you check in your browser? Does your browser access the internet through a proxy?

Comment: @PhilippReichart lol!!! sorry i've been sick the last few days and came back to work today, so, i'm a bit off. Sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CURL` is saying:

```
curl -v http://www.amazon.co.jp/gp/seller/sell-your-stuff.html
* About to connect() to www.amazon.co.jp port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 176.32.120.128... connected
> GET /gp/seller/sell-your-stuff.html HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.23.1 (x86_64-pc-win32) libcurl/7.23.1 OpenSSL/0.9.8r zlib/1.2.5
> Host: www.amazon.co.jp
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 301 MovedPermanently
```

Please note **`HTTP/1.1 301 MovedPermanently`**. Are you sure you have received `404` and not `301`? This is usual web practice, 301 header means that content was placed in some other location and user (browser) should navigate to it.

Also please make sure that `HttpURLConnection` allows redirection.

Comment: If i change url to 'https://www.amazon.co.jp/gp/seller/sell-your-stuff.html' from 'http://www.amazon.co.jp/gp/seller/sell-your-stuff.html', it starts giving 301.

Comment: With `-H "User-Agent: foo"` you get the actual page content. A 403 Forbidden with a "please don't crawl us" message would have been a lot nicer on Amazon's part, though :/

Answer (score 2):

Add a proper header value for "User-Agent"

```
connection.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Safari");
```

Comment: Interestingly, Amazon.co.jp seems to 404 any UA containing `curl` (propbably to prevent scraping). Even a bogus UA like `foo` works.

Comment: yeah , setting UA gives 200 , but any reason why this happens ?

Comment: This most likely happens to prevent programs/spiders from downloading all catalogue data off Amazon.co.jp (which most likely is a violation of their TOS anyway).

Comment: Still i don't understand why changing 'http' to 'https' gives 301

Comment: My suggestion is that Amazon simple has some filter for checking UA value.